# Can't create/modify gifs with Mono

Tags: c#, image-processing, mono, gif

I'm trying to add unit tests to the .Net ImageProcessor library: https://github.com/cosmo0/ImageProcessor/tree/tests

I'm working on Xamarin/Mono on my Mac. Mono seems to have a few problems with animated gifs images.
For my unit tests, I have a bunch of test images, and I load them all and run transformations on each of them. Each time I apply a filter (brightness for instance), it fails when trying to re-create an image.

The failing line is here : https://github.com/cosmo0/ImageProcessor/blob/tests/src/ImageProcessor/Imaging/Formats/GifFormat.cs#L95

It's just an `Image.FromStream(stream);`. I'm guessing the stream is wrong ; I tried to save it to a file, and indeed the file is not readable by the image viewer. The weird thing is that on Windows, it seems to be passing the tests perfectly fine: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/cosmo0/imageprocessor

Any idea what I could do to check the stream or fix it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Just a data point: `TestApplyEffectBrightness` on `format-Penguins.gif` seems to work okay on linux.

Comment: Hey @jester I'm the author of the library. Thanks for testing. To clarify, it's animated gifs that are the issue. If you have the means to test/debug that it would be amazing. I only have a windows box so I can't debug as I can't get Xamarin to work with Mono.

Comment: With `format-animated.gif` I get exception from [OctreeQuantizer.cs line 534](https://github.com/cosmo0/ImageProcessor/blob/tests/src/ImageProcessor/Imaging/OctreeQuantizer.cs#L534) but that seems to be a different problem.

Comment: Hmmm.. That's a worry. I wish it all just worked like it does on Windows!

Comment: `throw new ArgumentException("Didn't expect this!");`  Hah!  not the best exception message.

Comment: If it works on one platform and not another, that's either a bug or an undocumented missing feature. Post as a bug to Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset the stream before calling

`Image.FromStream(stream)`

like this :

`stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Comment: There's already a `stream.Position = 0;` isn't that the same ?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to flush as well? Serious question.